# WPF controlling objects on DataGrid new-item row when CanUserAddRows=true

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I'm using a WPF DataGrid bound to an `ObservableCollection<T>` where each row (aka instance of T) contains a browse and a delete button that are bound as commands to methods of T.

The problem is that I'm using `CanUserAddRows=true` for data-entry and there is no way to disable the delete button for the new row (since that instance of T isn't instantiated yet)

Does anyone know of a workaround?  Is there any way to control objects on the new-item row? Code-behind or thru binding is fine at this point - I'm desperate!

Comment: Did you try handling [LoadingRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.loadingrow%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) event or maybe in your case [LoadingRowDetails](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.loadingrowdetails%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Ron.  That got me started at least.  I'm looking into how to replace the new row placeholder template with my own.  It's getting pretty arcane and I feel like I'm fighting the framework.  Is using the DataGrid really supposed to be this hard?  It seems like the missing piece of the puzzle is that there's no DataGrid designer like there was for WinForms.  Am I missing something important?

Comment: It must not be that hard, maybe,if you give more details on what you are trying to do, I can help more.

Comment: You mean like this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757571/why-are-the-datagrid-delete-command-buttons-disabled  ;-)  But yeah, I don't think it should be this hard.

Comment: (sorry, the commenting system screwed me there)  My understanding of the problem has evolved to the core issue that the grid control creates an placeholder row when CanUserAddRows=true that is represented by a NewItemTemplate that is apparently a copy of the template defined for 'real' rows.  Currently I'm focusing on how to substitute my own template, either in code at load/unload time or using XAML.  Both approaches are dead-ends so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I unserstand correctly, you want to set IsEnabled property of a button in a new Row to be false;

If by *new row* you mean a Row that has not yet been edited, then I think it is better to initially set the IsEnabled property of that button to be false, and when an edit ocurred, change it to be true. Handle [RowEditEnding event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.roweditending%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

If this is not the case and you want to be able to set this property after a row is added to your datagrid, since your datagrid is bound to an observable collection, maybe you might like to handle [ObservableCollection.CollectionChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Comment: That's an interesting angle.  Let me play around with that approach.  Thanks.

Comment: Two days Fighting with this issue. TKS.